# localizedcurrency filter raise 'non well formed numeric value' after division

Tags: twig, intl, twig-extension

I'm using Twig for render a template that contains something like this:

```
{{ any_int_number / 100.0|localizedcurrency('EUR') }}
```

That `localizedcurrency` filter comes from `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl` and allows to convert a number in the right format based on the locale currently set.

If I leave that `/100.0` division there, I'm getting the following error:

```
 A non well formed numeric value encountered in /****/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code on line 136
```

Now, if I do something like this, it will work perfectly:

```
{{ 3.99 |localizedcurrency('EUR') }}
```

It's hard to figure out which type is returned after that division and why this error occurs, it looks like an issue, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters have a higher precedence than mathematical calculations in `twig`. You should add parentheses

```
{{ (any_int_number / 100.0)|localizedcurrency('EUR') }}
```